# React Material UI Autocomplete resetting input after every keystroke in Karma+Jasmine continuous test

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, react-testing-library

I have a test where I'm simulating a user typing into a Material UI Autocomplete field. When I run the test using `karma start karma.conf.js --single-run` everything works fine, but when the tests are running in continuous mode (e.g, after a file is edited), it fails due to the Autocomplete input resetting after every keystroke.

I'm using Jasmine for my test framework, Karma as the runner, and [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) for the rendering/user input.

My component code looks something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
          id="combo-box-demo"
          options={topFilms}
          onInputChange={(e, val, reason) => {
            console.log(`input value: "${val}"`);
            console.log(`reason: "${reason}"`);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And my test is like:

```
describe('App test', () => {
  it('renders autocomplete', async () => {
    const {getByRole} = render(<App />);
    // Get Autocomplete input box.
    const ac = getByRole('textbox');
    // Type some text.
    await userEvent.type(ac, 'Hello!');

    expect(ac.value).toBe('Hello!');

    // When Karma browser window doesn't have focus, every key press resets the
    // input value due.
  });
})
```

Now, when I run w/ `--single-run` the input gets populated as I would expect and I see console.log output like:

```
LOG: 'input value: "H"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
LOG: 'input value: "He"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
LOG: 'input value: "Hel"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
LOG: 'input value: "Hell"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
LOG: 'input value: "Hello"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
LOG: 'input value: "Hello!"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
```

But when I have it in continuous mode and edit something, triggering a refresh, it fails with logs like:

```
LOG: 'input value: "H"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
LOG: 'input value: ""'
LOG: 'reason: "reset"'
LOG: 'input value: "e"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
LOG: 'input value: ""'
LOG: 'reason: "reset"'
LOG: 'input value: "l"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
LOG: 'input value: ""'
LOG: 'reason: "reset"'
LOG: 'input value: "l"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
LOG: 'input value: ""'
LOG: 'reason: "reset"'
LOG: 'input value: "o"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
LOG: 'input value: ""'
LOG: 'reason: "reset"'
LOG: 'input value: "!"'
LOG: 'reason: "input"'
LOG: 'input value: ""'
LOG: 'reason: "reset"'
```

Notice a 'reset' happens after every keystroke, clearing out the input field.

What would be different about `--single-run` vs `continuous` mode that would cause this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Minimal repro case at https://github.com/joeltine/mui-autocomplete-karma-bug-repro. Just `npm install` and run tests with `npx karma start karma.conf.js`. Edit the `App.test.js` file to see the bug. This seems to be some kind of issue with browser window focus. A `--single-run` forces focus on the browser window, but continuous runs do not necessarily have focus.

Comment: From the docs, `singleRun` actually is continuous integration mode.

Comment: OK, is that a clue to fix the problem? Or just a correction of my question?

Comment: please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or at least the `package.json` and `karma.conf.js` so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: @joeltine how are you running the continuous mode?

Comment: `karma start my.conf.js`

Comment: OK, I created a minimal repro case for this @ https://github.com/joeltine/mui-autocomplete-karma-bug-repro. Just checkout the project, `npm install` and run the tests `npx karma start karma.conf.js`. The first run passes but editing the `App.test.js` file causes it to fail w/ the issue mentioned in the original post. I think I've narrowed down this issue to something with focus on the browser window. E.g., if I start Karma with iframes disabled `{client: {useIframe:false}` the problem goes away as it forces focus on the window for every test run.

Comment: your workaround looks good, any reason you don't want to use `useIframe: false`?

Comment: Ya, `useIframe: false` forces focus on the browser window, which is unpleasant if you're actively editing a test in your ide.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve it with [`clearOnBlur={false}`](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.0/packages/mui-material/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L706):

```
<Autocomplete
    id="combo-box-demo"
    clearOnBlur={false}
    options={topFilms}
    onInputChange={(e, val, reason) => {
      console.log(`input value: "${val}"`);
      console.log(`reason: "${reason}"`);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
/>
```

By default, [Autocomplete](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/) clears the input field on blur (a.k.a. when it loses focus) if the text entered doesn't match any of its options, which is the case here - your test types `Hello!`, but there are no options with that string.

Alternatively, you could set `freeSolo={true}`, but that would allow you to enter anything instead of picking an existing option.

Comment: Thanks, @Fapaz. This does work in so far as the tests will consistently pass. However, it's not the UI functionality I need. I need `clearOnBlur=true` otherwise the user could type a bad value, blur the field, and the input will remain populated with an incomplete value.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out whose bug this is, if anyone's. Doesn't feel like it's MUI. It almost feels like a browser issue. Why would a browser force a blur on every keystroke, regardless of what the window focus state is? Maybe the testing library is doing something weird?

Comment: @joeltine It does seem like the webview launched by Karma is the one to blame. For some reason it's losing and regaining the focus on each key typed, which is making the Autocomplete trigger its clear function.